# net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error on call of ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

In below jQuery code, I call get_chat_message() which contain ajax code to get data continuously on particular time interval.

But after some time, if it does not get any data then it will return below error:

> ```
> net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
> ```

```
var refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () {
  var chat_id = $(".chat_id").val();
  if (chat_id != "") {
    get_chat_message();
  }
}, 2500);

function get_chat_message(){
  $(".inbox").scrollTop($(".inbox").height());

  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/get_chat_message",
    type: 'POST',
    data: {chat_id: chat_id},
    success: function (data) {

      var current_content = $(".inbox").html();
      $(".inbox").html(current_content + data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
      alert('error; ' + eval(error));
    }

  });
```

Comment: From a quick Google it appears that this can occur when a timeout happens. It's part of the reason that AJAX polling is a really bad idea. I'd strongly suggest you instead use Web Sockets or Server Side Events instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for your suggestion I will try it.